# Order of execution and purpose of .profile vs .zshrc

Tags: shell, zsh, .profile

Few questions:

- What is a distinct purpose of `.profile` and `.zshrc`?
- What gets called first when the shell comes to life?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~/.profile` is only loaded when running `zsh` in `sh` compatibility mode, otherwise it reads `.zprofile`, as well as `.zshrc` for interactive and `.zlogin` for login shells.

Their purpose develops from when they're loaded. As `.zshrc` is loaded for interactive shells, set the aliases etc. you expect in such cases there.

`.profile` has the additional property that it's loaded by several other shells as well (e.g. `bash`, unless it finds something more specific; or `ksh`) in one way or another, so you can store configuration for multiple shells in this file.

Relevant excerpts from `man zshall`, emphasis mine:

> **STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES**
>   Commands  are  first  read  from `/etc/zshenv`; [...]
>
> Commands are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`.  If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from `/etc/zprofile` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`.  Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`.  Finally, if the shell is a login shell, `/etc/zlogin` and  `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin`  are read.
>
> **COMPATIBILITY**
>   Zsh tries to emulate sh or ksh when it is invoked as sh or ksh respectively; [...]
>
> **The  usual  zsh startup/shutdown scripts are not executed**.  Login shells source `/etc/profile` followed by `$HOME/.profile`.  If the ENV environment variable is set on invocation, `$ENV` is sourced after the profile scripts.  The value of `ENV` is subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion before being interpreted as a pathname.  Note that the PRIVILEGED option also affects the execution of startup files.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to add an example? Say both .profile and .zprofile are present, but zsh is being run in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

The zsh manual, section 5 "Files" [1] has a section that shows the precise sequence of dot files read at login and logout.  This is specific to zsh, and does not cover the interaction with `.profile`, ie, compatibility.  Nonetheless, I have found this helpful in structuring my zsh dot files.

[1] http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files

Comment: link outdated..